# jQuery Mobile, Iphone scroll down activates swipe right

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, browser, touch, mobile-safari

IPhone safari scroll initiates swipe while using jQuery mobile. I learnt that using horizontalDistanceThreshold we can limit the event to how many pixels we want. But this is still a issue. Is there a way decouple these two events?

Answer (score 0):

I found this useful, but be careful about the JQM version: 1.4.0 is ok for some devices, 1.4.4 is ok for others but interferes with the change event of slider widget, now we have 1.4.5 (not try with this one).

You have to play a little bit with the values and see what are best for you.
Take a look to http://api.jquerymobile.com/swipe/ also for more options.

```
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){

     $.event.special.swipe.horizontalDistanceThreshold = 60;
        // (default: 30) (pixels)

     $.event.special.swipe.verticalDistanceThreshold = 50; 
        // (default: 75) (pixels) – Swipe vertical displacement must be less than this.     

});
```